# "No value accessor for..." with model-driven form

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms, angular2-formbuilder

I'm trying to build a provisional dropdown menu using Material Design components and can't figure out why my `ControlValueAccessor` isn't working. Here's the relevant part of the code:

```
import {
    AfterViewInit,
    Component,
    ElementRef,
    forwardRef,
    Input,
    OnInit,
    Provider,
    ViewChild
} from '@angular/core';

import {
    NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
    ControlValueAccessor,
    CORE_DIRECTIVES
} from '@angular/common';

import { MdCard } from '@angular2-material/card';

import {
    MdInput,
    MD_INPUT_DIRECTIVES
} from '@angular2-material/input';

import { MD_LIST_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular2-material/list';

declare var module: {
    id: string;
};

export const MD_SELECT_VALUE_ACCESSOR = new Provider(
    NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, { useExisting: forwardRef(() => MdSelect), multi: true });

const noop = () => {};

@Component({
    selector: 'md-select',
    moduleId: module.id,
    template: `
        <div>
            <md-input readOnly type="text" [placeholder]="placeholder" (click)="selectClick()">
                <i md-suffix class="fa fa-sort-desc"></i>
            </md-input>
            <md-card [ngClass]="{ visible: menuVisible }" (blur)="menuBlur()">
                <md-list>
                    <md-list-item class="md-option" *ngFor="let option of options" (click)="optionClick(option)" [ngClass]="{ 'selected': option.selected }">
                        {{option.name}}
                    </md-list-item>            
                </md-list>
            </md-card>
        </div>
    `,
    styleUrls: [
        'md-select.component.css'
    ],
    directives: [
        CORE_DIRECTIVES,
        MdCard,
        MdInput,
        MD_INPUT_DIRECTIVES,
        MD_LIST_DIRECTIVES
    ],
    providers: [MD_SELECT_VALUE_ACCESSOR]
})
export class MdSelect implements ControlValueAccessor {
    @Input() multiple: boolean;
    @Input() placeholder: string;
    private _value: string;
    onChanged: (_: any) => void = noop;
    onTouched: () => void = noop;
    options: MdOption[] = [];
    menuVisible: boolean = false;
    selectedOption: MdOption;
    private _selectedOptions: MdOption[] = [];
    addOption(option: MdOption) {
        this.options.push(option);
        if (option.selected && (!this.selectedOption || this.multiple)) {
            this.selectedOption = option;
            this.value = this.selectedOption.name;
        }
    }
    selectClick() {
        if (!this.menuVisible) {
            this.menuVisible = true;
        }
    }
    optionClick(option: MdOption) {
        if (option) {
            if (this.multiple) {
                option.selected = !option.selected;
            } else {
                this.options.filter(option => option.selected).forEach(option => option.selected = false);
                option.selected = true;
            }
            this.onChanged('value');
        }
        this.menuBlur();
    }
    menuBlur() {
        this.menuVisible = false;
    }
    get value(): string {
        return this.options.filter(option => option.selected).map(option => option.name).join(', ')
    }
    set value(value: string) {
        if (value !== this._value) {
            this._value = value; // TODO
            this.onChanged('value');
        }
    }
    writeValue(value: any): void {
        console.log('writeValue("' + value + '")')
        this.value = value;
    }
    registerOnChange(fn: (_: any) => void): void {
        this.onChanged = (_: any) => { console.log('onChange("' + _ + '")'); fn(_); };
    }
    registerOnTouched(fn: () => void): void {
        this.onTouched = () => { console.log('onTouched()'); fn(); }
    }
}

@Component({
    selector: 'md-option',
    template: `
        <div #wrapper>
            <ng-content></ng-content>
        </div>    
    `
})
export class MdOption implements AfterViewInit {
    @ViewChild('wrapper') wrapper: ElementRef;
    @Input() disabled: boolean;
    name: string;
    @Input() selected: boolean;
    @Input() value: string;
    constructor(private select: MdSelect) { }
    ngAfterViewInit() {
        if (this.wrapper) {
            let name = this.wrapper.nativeElement.innerHTML;
            this.name = name ? name.trim() : 'EMPTY';
        }
        this.select.addOption(this);
    }
}
```

This is the part of the template where it is used

```
<div class="md-form-control">
    <md-select placeholder="Shift" class="shift" formControlName="shift">
        <md-option *ngFor="let s of shifts" [value]="s.id" [ngValue]="s.id"
            [selected]="s.id === shift.id">
            {{s.name}}
        </md-option>  
    </md-select>
</div>
```

and here's the form setup

```
private initForm() {
    ...
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
        shift: [this.shift.name],
        ...
    })
}
```

If I try to run this code I get

> platform-browser.umd.js:1900 ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: No value accessor for 'shift'

What did I miss?

Comment: Did you add `MdSelect` to `directives: [...]` where you're using it?

Comment: Yeah, `MdSelect` and `MdOption` both.I was going to create a plnkr, but that had trouble injecting `MdSelect` into `MdOption` (see http://plnkr.co/edit/RfbSN1xMtD9a7PdCWRXY), so I'm out of ideas at the moment.

Comment: As far as I know this is not supposed to work.  
There is a way to inject the host element but not the parent element.

Comment: It works on my machine(TM) at home though ;)

Comment: With above Plunker?

Comment: Not with the plunker, but with the code snippet from my question which does the exact same thing (`constructor(private select: MdSelect) { }`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the reason while implementing an MD textarea control and checking with `MdInput` from `@angular2-material`.

There are currently 2 barrels containing `NG_VALUE_ACCCESSOR` and `ControlValueAccessor`, `@angular/common` and `@angular/forms`. I guess that with the **new forms** they moved the accessor stuff to `forms` and the old implementation in `common` remains for those who haven't switched over yet.

However, there is no warning in case you happen to import the wrong components.

Hence, if you are using the **new forms module**, the solution is to change

```
import {
    NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
    ControlValueAccessor,
    DefaultValueAccessor
} from '@angular/common';
```

to

```
import {
    NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
    ControlValueAccessor,
    DefaultValueAccessor
} from '@angular/forms';
```

You may also have to change

```
export const YOUR_CUSTOM_CONTROL_ACCESSOR = new Provider(
    NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, { useExisting: forwardRef(() => YourCustomControlAccessor), multi: true });
```

to

```
export const YOUR_CUSTOM_CONTROL_ACCESSOR: any = {
    provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, 
    useExisting: forwardRef(() => YourCustomControlAccessor), 
    multi: true 
};
```

Comment: Hi, 
"...  while implementing an MD textarea control ... " 
Any plans to share the MD textarea control ?

Comment: it's just a temporary solution until the Material2 team comes up with an official textarea control.